# Laptop built-in camera disappears and come back every few seconds

Tags: windows-10, camera, integrated-camera

My laptop's camera toggles uncontrollably. I noticed it disappears and comes back in seconds or less. There's some kind of hardware change because the device manager refreshes itself.

Here's a visual example from the Zoom video settings, because it shows it clearly.

*The camera device is changing to *screen-capture-recorder* but it's just ShareX driver/device for screen recording. When I uninstall it the results are the same except it toggles between my WebCam to nothing, so I don't think the problem is there.

---

- I tried uninstalling and updating the webcam driver
- Haven't seen anything useful in the event viewer

---

Any idea what's happening? Maybe hints for things I can check/follow to discover the problem?

[image]

---

Asus N550JV, Windows 10, 21H1, 19043.1110

Comment: Update also BIOS, Chipset, and Video,  restart and test.  If it is still turning on and off, replace the camera.

Comment: I've seen this happen a few times because Microsoft Windows Update pushes a driver for a webcam that is not suitable, resulting in a driver crash each time. A rollback of the update following by installing a driver from the manufacturer website usually is what fixes it.